# Lightning Visual Force Page URL redirecting to Classic Visual force page URL

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have an formula field with HYPERLINK to an VF Page below is the Formula Field code

```
IF (TEXT(<fld name>) ==  'something', HYPERLINK('/apex/page-name?param1=5&id='+Id, MY BUTTON IMAGE,'_self'), NULL)
```

The above code generates URL as below (when i see using inspect element)

> https://{instance-name}.lightning.force.com/apex/page-name?param1=abc&id=

But on layout when i click on image it redirects to below URL

```
https://<instance>--c.cs78.visual.force.com/apex/page-name?param1=abc&id=<sf-id>
```

Can someone explain why is this behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: If you're on lightning UI, it would be common as first it would try to open the page in Lightning domain followed by in Classic.

Comment: any solution for this... because if we redirect to a VF page from a Lightning component, it opens up in lightning UI

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: problem is only with url within formula, it doesn't work as redirect work within lightning component

Answer (score -1):

Lightning and classic url is different. to resolve this condition on redirected page you can use this script as a reference.

"script"
        if(typeof sforce !== 'undefined' && sforce !== null && '{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}' === 'Theme4d'){
            sforce.one.navigateToURL('{!'/one/one.app#/ }');
        } else {
            window.top.location = '{!'/}';
        }
   "/script"

Hope this helps !!

Comment: how this would work in formula field ??

Comment: formula field you are using to redirecting to vf page is fine. you can write that script to redirect to lightning mode instead of classic one.

i don't think you can achieve this by formula.